# How to Handle multiple NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I have a function lets say onTimer

```
-(void)onTimer {
       * Some Operation *
}
```

I want to call this method like in this way...

For 10 seconds it should call on every 0.2 seconds.... then in another 10seconds, duration of calling this method should be increased..... by doing this it will appear operations getting slow from fast mode... and it will stop at the end.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fairly easy to accomplish with 2 timers. In the .h file, declare 2 timers:

```
float intervalYouWant;
NSTimer * timer1;
NSTimer * timer2;
```

In the .m file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad; {
  intervalYouWant = 0.2;
  timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intervalYouWant target:self selector:@selector(methodForTimer1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(changeTimer1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)changeTimer1; {
  [timer1 invalidate];
  timer1 = nil;
  intervalYouWant += amountYouWantToAdd;
  timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intervalYouWant target:self selector:@selector(methodForTimer1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

That should cancel the first timer every 10 seconds, and restart it with a new time interval. Don't forget to invalidate the timers in the `dealloc` method. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start the timer in non repeat mode

```
float interval   = 0.2; //global variable

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(timerSelector:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

..........
..........

-(void) timerSelector:(NSTimer *)timer{
  static float timeConsumed = 0.0;
  //do your task which you want to do here
  ............
  ............

 // in the end
   if(timeConsumed > 10.0){
     interval    = 0.5;   //increase the interval so it decrease the speed..
   }else if(timeConsumed > 20.0){
     interval    = 1.0;
   }... go on like this until you stop it..

   timeConsumed   += interval;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(timerSelector:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Written from memory..So syntax errors possible..Correct yourself..hope this helps..

Comment: I have entered these values in your code float intervalYouWant = 0.2;
float amountYouWantToAdd=0.5; but its not working fine... it just keep running on with 0.2 speed for infinite time..... its not increasing time and it doesnt stopping after few time. My task is to call that method fast on startup and slows down after certain perioid... just like Casino Scroll

Comment: Then edit your question with your code..Also where you setting variable interval...timeConsumed should be a static variable